# Electronics Goods Repair

Tags: consumer-protection, india, warranties

Let's say I have an electronic product that is out of warranty. Now that the product is no more covered under warranty, shouldn't the respective company be responsible for providing services for repair at a cost?

To explain the situation here. I purchased product 'X' 2 years back(which had a 1-year warranty). Now that the product is damaged and clearly requires servicing. I take it to the authorized service center and they say that the only option is to purchase a new device instead because they don't repair product 'X' post-warranty.

My question is, is this legal what the company is doing? Since I believe this could be intentional to make us buy their products.

Comment: Unfortunately, I have not heard of any such law. Companies are not required to grant more service than the obligatory warranty (whose exact terms differ between countries). Your options are: Find somebody else that fixes it, buy a new one, or buy from a different vendor.

Comment: In a professional context, companies typically make special agreements with their suppliers, requiring them to provide service and spare parts for a certain time. But as a private buyer, it's almost impossible to get such an agreement.

Comment: In Germany car companies have to provide spare parts for a specific time after a car is no longer being sold. I don't know if they also have to provide a repair service but they have to sell spare parts.

Comment: @somega indeed, they need only provide parts and a list of specs, no services.